# High memory in rancher

Tags: node.js, newrelic, rancher

Is there any way in rancher to detect what consumes so much memory in the application, it is a web in nodejs

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- From the Global view, navigate to the cluster that you want to view metrics.

2- Select Nodes in the navigation bar.

3- Select a specific node and click on its name.

4- Click on Node Metrics.

Comment: Hello, here is the screenshot. https://ibb.co/Tcw4FTH  We still cannot locate what is the cause of the memory increase

Comment: New relic vm https://ibb.co/Zm9b4KC